# LIQUID TEMPLATE LANGUAGE Twilio Studio Variables

Tags: twilio, twilio-studio

Does anyone know how I can assign liquid template language variables to widget variables?

```
{% assign name='{{widgets.send_and_reply_3.inbound.Body}}'%}
```

This does not seem to work. I have removed the **`''`** and that does not work either. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

When using widget variables within other liquid tags you don't need to include the `{` or `}` brackets. So this should work for you:

```
{% assign name = widgets.send_and_reply_3.inbound.Body %}
```